# Arata Naru Sekai OVA, premise and explanation of the ending?

Tags: arata-naru-sekai

Madhouse's recent OVA, "Arata Naru Sekai" is a one-shot 30 minute OVA without much background. I can gather that:

- time-travel is prevalent in this world
- the 4 girls seemed to have traveled far into the future
- there was perhaps some kind of imminent disaster in the past
- the disaster perhaps happened very soon after their jump into the future
- the past that they lived in was already starting to fall apart

So what happened after the cell phone was destroyed? Was it all a dream? Or did it transport them back to the past or some alternate reality?

EDIT: I found the [synopsis at MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/14373/Arata_naru_Sekai%3a_Mirai-hen) which sort of confirms some of the premise (though I don't really see any evidence for some of the claims in the MAL synopsis), but it doesn't shed any light on the ending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anime is a part of what is called a multiple multimedia experience. The anime is the third part of the story, whereas the light novel and the manga fill in the stories of the people who went to the past and those who stayed in the present. You have to read all of the parts to really understand the anime and its ending.